# Confleunt Kafka - return messages after timestamp

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Using this code I iterate over a cloud hosted Confluent Kafka topic:

```
import pyspark
import copy
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
import json
import sklearn
from confluent_kafka import Consumer,TopicPartition
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
 
conf = {}
topic = "price-data"
conf['bootstrap.servers'] = 'pkc-4yyd6.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092'
conf['security.protocol'] = 'SASL_SSL'
conf['sasl.mechanisms'] = 'PLAIN'
conf['sasl.username'] = '****'
conf['sasl.password'] = '****'
conf['auto.offset.reset'] = 'earliest'
conf['group.id'] = 'python_example_group_1'
conf['default.topic.config'] = {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}

consumer = Consumer(conf)
consumer.subscribe([topic])
consumer.poll()
consumer.seek(TopicPartition(topic, 1, 0))

counter = 0
try:
  while True:
    message = consumer.poll()
    if message is None:
      continue
    elif message.error():
        print('Error')
    else:
        try:
          counter = counter + 1
          if counter % 1000 == 0 : 
            print('counter'  , counter)
        except Exception as e:
              print("Exception occurred parsing message" , e)
                
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt exception")
    pass
finally:
    # Leave group and commit final offsets
    consumer.close()
```

displays:

```
counter 1000
counter 2000
counter 3000
counter 4000
counter 5000
counter 6000
counter 7000
counter 8000
counter 9000
counter 10000
counter 11000
counter 12000
counter 13000
counter 14000
counter 15000
counter 16000
counter 17000
counter 18000
```

If I change the partition to 2 instead of 1:

```
consumer.seek(TopicPartition(topic, 2, 0))
```

Then 4000 records are returned:

```
counter 1000
counter 2000
counter 3000
counter 4000
```

From reading https://medium.com/@hellbreak/how-a-kafka-consumer-can-start-reading-messages-from-a-different-offset-and-get-back-to-the-start-eee28dc19428:

> If a topic has 4 partitions and I have only one consumer C1 in my
> group, this guy will get messages from all the partitions. If I had
> another consumer C2 to the same group, each of consumer will receive
> data from two partitions. The limit in this logic is when the number
> of consumers are higher than the number of partitions, some of the
> consumers will get no messages because of all the partitions are
> already assigned. But this is another field, which involves
> scalability.

As I'm the sole consumer of the Kafka topic then how do I use `consumer.seek` to return all messages after a certain timestamp to the consumer ?

Comment: The Java API has a lookup offsets by timestamp method. Not sure about the Python client